# Using a custom transporter for Rust's hyper http crate

Tags: rust, hyper

**ps: the answer below helped but it's not the answer I need, I have a new problem and I edited the question**

I'm trying to make a custom transporter for the [hyper http crate](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/dfa1bb291d71978820e8077be94c1d5837935bbc/src/client/dispatch.rs#L59), so I can transport http packets in my own way.

Hyper's http client can be passed a custom  https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/hyper/client/connect/trait.Connect.html here:

`pub fn build<C, B>(&self, connector: C) -> Client<C, B> where    C: Connect + Clone,    B: HttpBody + Send,    B::Data: Send,`

If we look at

```
impl<S, T> Connect for S where    

S: Service<Uri, Response = T> + Send + 'static,    

S::Error: Into<Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync>>,    

S::Future: Unpin + Send,    

T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Connection + Unpin + Send + 'static,
```

the type `T`, which is the type of the `Response`, must implement `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite`, so I've chosen `type Response = Cursor<Vec<u8>>`.

Here's my custom transporter with a `Response` of type `std::io::Cursor` wrapped in `CustomResponse` so I can implement `AsyncWrite` and `AsyncRead` to it:

```
use hyper::service::Service;
use core::task::{Context, Poll};
use core::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::io::Cursor;
use hyper::client::connect::{Connection, Connected};
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct CustomTransporter;

unsafe impl Send for CustomTransporter {}

impl CustomTransporter {
    pub fn new() -> CustomTransporter {
        CustomTransporter{}
    }
}

impl Connection for CustomTransporter {
    fn connected(&self) -> Connected {
        Connected::new()
    }
}

pub struct CustomResponse {
    //w: Cursor<Vec<u8>>,
    v: Vec<u8>,
    i: i32
}

unsafe impl Send for CustomResponse {
    
}

impl Connection for CustomResponse {
    fn connected(&self) -> Connected {
        println!("connected");
        Connected::new()
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for CustomResponse {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        self.i+=1;
        if self.i >=3 {
            println!("poll_read for buf size {}", buf.capacity());
            buf.put_slice(self.v.as_slice());
            println!("did poll_read");
            Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
        } else {
            println!("poll read pending, i={}", self.i);
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

impl AsyncWrite for CustomResponse {
    fn poll_write(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &[u8]
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize, std::io::Error>>{
        //let v = vec!();
        println!("poll_write____");

        let s = match std::str::from_utf8(buf) {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
        };

        println!("result: {}, size: {}, i: {}", s, s.len(), self.i);
        if self.i>=0{
            //r
            Poll::Ready(Ok(s.len()))
        }else{
            println!("poll_write pending");
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
    fn poll_flush(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), std::io::Error>> {
        println!("poll_flush");
        if self.i>=0{
            println!("DID poll_flush");
            Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
        }else{
            println!("poll_flush pending");
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }

    fn poll_shutdown(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), std::io::Error>>
    {
        println!("poll_shutdown");
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}


impl Service<hyper::Uri> for CustomTransporter {
    type Response = CustomResponse;
    type Error = hyper::http::Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>> + Send>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        println!("poll_ready");
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
        //Poll::Pending
    }

    fn call(&mut self, req: hyper::Uri) -> Self::Future {
        println!("call");
        // create the body
        let body: Vec<u8> = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nDate: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\nServer: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\nLast-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT\nContent-Length: 88\nContent-Type: text/html\nConnection: Closed<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>".as_bytes()
            .to_owned();
        // Create the HTTP response
        let resp = CustomResponse{
            //w: Cursor::new(body),
            v: body,
            i: 0
        };
         
        // create a response in a future.
        let fut = async move{
            Ok(resp)
        };
        println!("gonna return from call");
        // Return the response as an immediate future
        Box::pin(fut)
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
let connector = CustomTransporter::new();
let client: Client<CustomTransporter, hyper::Body> = Client::builder().build(connector);
let mut res = client.get(url).await.unwrap();
```

However, it gets stuck and hyper never reads my response, but it writes the GET to it.

**Here's a complete project for testing:** https://github.com/lzunsec/rust_hyper_custom_transporter/blob/39cd036fc929057d975a71969ccbe97312543061/src/custom_req.rs

RUn like this:

```
cargo run http://google.com
```

Comment: It looks to me like the ` Pin::new(&mut self.w)` does not survive long enough.

Comment: @Unapiedra I don't get it. Rust, as far as I know, prevents this. If it didn't live enough then I'd have undefined behaviour, I guess? How should i try to fix this to see if this is the error?

Comment: The `Send` is `unsafe`, which I guess might lead to this. Anyway, here's some link: https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/1955

Comment: @Unapiedra do you have any idea on why this could be a problem? In theory, if I do not use `unsafe` in my code, there should be no undefined behaviour

Comment: I don't think adding yet another bounty will solve the problem...

Comment: There is no UB! The linked issue gives a hint on what's happening. Something goes out of scope, and the error that you get when running your code says `ChannelClosed`. There is no UB, just _unwanted_ behavior. Try to keep your  `let r = Pin::new(&mut self.w).poll_read(cx, buf);` longer in scope, maybe? (I tried and couldn't get it to work.)

Comment: @Unapiedra unfortunately this is not the problem. I discovered that it closes the channel because I sent the response before it sent the `GET / google.com` HTTP request. I changed the code so it only returns the answer after the GET is sent, however hyper gets stuck and never reads my answer, even though I receive the GET request. Please take a look at the new code.

Comment: @Unapiedra new code: https://github.com/lzunsec/rust_hyper_custom_transporter/blob/39cd036fc929057d975a71969ccbe97312543061/src/custom_req.rs. Seems like I'm close to the answer, please tell me if you know what's happening. No more Pin and Cursors being used now, so that error is not the cause

Comment: @Unapiedra I commented a LOT of things on hyper and still couldn't figure out why it gets stuck and do not read from my messages

Answer (score 6):

> I cannot simply implement `Send` to `Future`, and I cannot change `Future` by a wrapper. What should I do here?

It looks like the problem is your `Service::Future` is missing the `Send` constraint. The future being returned in `call` is already `Send` so it will work with the simple change:

```
impl Service<hyper::Uri> for CustomTransporter {
    type Response = CustomResponse;
    type Error = hyper::http::Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>> + Send>>;
                                                                                  // ^^^^
    ...
```

---

Your code has a few other errors: un-inferred `vec!()`, `self: Pin<...>` missing `mut`, `CustomResponse` should be `pub`...

You can specify the `B` of `client` by using inference:

```
let client: Client<CustomTransporter, hyper::Body> = Client::builder().build(connector);
```

Or by using the turbofish operator on `build`:

```
let client = Client::builder().build::<CustomTransporter, hyper::Body>(connector);
```

---

I don't know enough about creating custom hyper transports to know if its *functional*, but these fixes make it compile. Hopefully it helps you make progress.

Comment: `let client = Client::<CustomTransporter>::builder().build(connector);` this does not work. What you meant by the defining the `B` parameter?

Comment: https://github.com/lzunsec/rust_hyper_custom_transporter/tree/91adf9ade257ac929252d3ecd20111866cd32685 here are my new modifications. I only get the `B` error, even though I made `let client = Client::<(), Body>::builder().build(connector);`

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna wait to see if anyone can help me with making the fake request work. Currently it runs but I get an error. https://github.com/lzunsec/rust_hyper_custom_transporter/tree/334d0f160255082e40c76e7b96d11ef1d006bce1

Comment: new bounty for you even though I didn't find the problem lol